# I need to center multiple images that each have their own div tag, within the container

Tags: css, image, alignment, center

I am trying to figure out how to center images located within their own , center them within the container. I have 8 images in 2 columns, 2 images per row left aligned. I need them centered aligned.

I found a way to center here:
[Aligning multiple images horizontally in the center of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434022/aligning-multiple-images-horizontally-in-the-center-of-a-div)

*Floating a block level item will push it to the left or right. "display:inline-block" on the IMG. And remove the float and position statements. Then "text-align:center" for the container div.*

But that way puts all the images into a single column. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my CSS controling the container and the images:

```
.container {
    width: 452px;
    height: 750px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
      }


      .item a img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.45),0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.45),0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.45),0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 0.7;
      }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/01.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/01t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/02.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/02t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div><p>
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/03.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/03t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/04.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/04t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/05.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/05t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/07.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/07t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>

    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/06.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/06t.JPG" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a rel="clearbox[gallery=Gallery,,comment=Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo]" href="../images/Dustin/10.JPG" title="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo"><img class="border" src="../images/Dustin/thumbs/10t.jpg" alt="Dirty South Ink Tattoo Shop Photo" /></a></div>
```

Comment: I think the key is to lay out the images the way you want them in one container, and then center that container. You may be centering the images inside their container, and then centering that container, which seems like doing it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images in your original attempt were most likely being forced into in a single column because your DIV was not wide enough.  Your images are 150px wide + 2x 3px padding + 2x 5px margin + 2x 1px border = 168px.

Many browsers still do not support `box-sizing:border-box` so for now, it would be better to steer clear of it, otherwise you'll have inconsistent results.

Removing the `box-sizing:border-box` and making your container 336px wide will center your images, alternatively wrapping the images in an inner container with the following CSS would also do the trick.

```
.inner_container{
  width:336px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nM8v3/1/)

Now of course, you will still have to accommodate older versions of IE but this should achieve your goal for modern browsers.

Comment: You are the bomb! I really appreciate it. Works in ie8 and 9 and that's all I care about really. Well FF and Chrome but generally if it works in ie, will work in those too though the reverse is not necessarily true.

Comment: FYI I left box-sizing:border-box in the CSS. It doesn't appear to cause any problems. I did accept the answer checkmark. Thanks again.

Comment: Keeping `box-sizing:border-box` will cause your content to be skewed 16px left in webkit browsers (and any other browser that supports the property) because it will reduce each img width to 142px so that the total width including padding and border the is 150px.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it based on your advice

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer is correct....i would use an additional inner wrapper and the text-align:center; property to make the whole thing cross browser compatible. I've had to figure this one out a couple of times for different tasks... basically i always come back to the same technique: i use an additional inner wrapper that acts like a normal block element and the text-align:center; property to make the whole thing cross browser compatible. anything i set or float inside that will STAY in the center ^.^ and i can adjust the width and padding to make the rows in twos or threes, or however far apart i need them.

Example CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.innerwrap {display:inline-block;}
.innerwrap div{
   padding:5px;
   margin:5px;
   float: left;
}
```

Used on your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/cwk6nd9c/1/