# Centering 3 images in css

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can center these 3 images, I have wrapped them in `<center>` but it isn't working?

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
}
.imgA1 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.imgB1 {
    z-index: 3;
    padding-left:95px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.imgC1 {
    z-index: 4;
    padding-left:-5px;
    padding-top: -25px;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<center>
    <img class="imgA1" src="/resources/images/loading_screen/13__-6PX._-69w.png">
    <img class="imgB1" src="/resources/images/loading_screen/photo<?php echo rand(1, 29); ?>.png">
    <img class="imgC1" src="/resources/images/loading_screen/12__-6PX._-NC.png">
</center>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have achieved using a fiddle.

Comment: By altering your code from

    img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 25px;
    }

to
    
    img {
        top: 25px;
        left: 25px;
    }

They aligned side-by-side. However, I'm sure you had a position of absolute for a reason, so I need to know why in order to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Did you want to center them side by side horizontally? Btw the `center` element has been deprecated and is now obsolete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning multiple images horizontally in the center of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434022/aligning-multiple-images-horizontally-in-the-center-of-a-div)

Comment: This was asked 4 years ago. We now use flex for this. Here's [how to align 3 images example](https://semicolon.dev/css/how-to-center-3-images-in-div-using-flex).

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use `<center>` tag. Read below

> [*`<center>` tag is obsolete. Although it may still work in some
>   browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any
>   time. Try to avoid using it.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

You can use `position:absolute` to put the image top of each other.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="imgA1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <img class="imgB1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <img class="imgC1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work, it didn't center it at all, it only centers text.

Comment: @zopohaj did you checked the snippet result

Comment: yes, all the images load next to each other, I'm trying to put the images on top of each other, you also didn't specify what I should do with the old css.

Comment: @zopohaj but your question was _**how I can center these 3 images**_...it does not say about top of each other...

Comment: @zopohaj If you want top of each other I will update my answer

Comment: Sorry but I thought my code would of said that the way I was aligning the images with padding. Please do update your question, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, it does work well but all the elements that come after it are displayed above it, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @zopohaj you want last element on the top or what...?

Comment: I have a <h1> after my <div class="wrapper"></div> and its displayed behind the images for some reason, surely it should come after the images.

Comment: This just makes it go above the images, it doesn't make it come after the images.

Comment: @zopohaj give some height to your wrapper div

Comment: I've just noticed that the top image's quality (not sure about the rest) is a little blurred, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @zopohaj Hello......see your question first what you have asked...if you have other problems ask another question...

Comment: I'm asking how to fix a problem with your answer.. its made my image blurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can center elements within their container pretty easily using `display: flex`, if the container is one-dimensional.

The following snippet contains an example of both a vertical and horizontal one-dimensional flexbox container.

```css
.horizontal-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #808080;
  margin: 5px;
}

.vertical-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  background: #808080;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-flex-container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
</div>

<div class="vertical-flex-container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" />
</div>
```

Setting `display: flex` enables the container to position its elements via flex.

The `flex-flow` property sets which direction the container is flowing. If set to `row`, the container will behave as if horizontal. If set to `column`, the container will behave as if vertical. The `nowrap` portion is included here to prevent wrapping of overflowed content.

For `row` containers, setting `justify-content: center` will place children in the vertical center of the container.
For `column` containers, settings `align-items: center` will place children in the horizontal center of the container.

Comment: This is next to each other, not on top of each other.

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain both flex directions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can center an image (vertically and horizontally).

https://jsfiddle.net/rachit5/Ge4YH/

```
<div class="center-my-content">
    <img src="http://www.harpseals.org/images/seals/whitecoat_on_back-photo-eric_baccega_npl-sm.jpg"/>
</div>

body{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
.center-my-content {
    height:80%;
    width:80%;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:0 auto;
}
img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using absolute positioning on the img tag. All images are being placed at that location then moving based off the padding and margin you are adding. Remove the absolute positioning. Also you shouldn't use the center tag but instead a div. This is how you should center three images.

```css
img {max-width:100%;}
.image-wrapper {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="image"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="smile"/></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="smile"/></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="smile"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't what I asked for, I asked for images on top, not next to each other.

Comment: I changed the snippet to what you wanted, simply by wrapping the images in divs