# How to avoid image overlapping

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="width:100%;text-align: center;">
  <div style="float:left; width:150px;max-width:150px;margin:5px">
    <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:150px;max-width:150px;margin:5px">
    <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:150px;max-width:150px;margin:5px">
    <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:150px;max-width:150px;margin:5px">
    <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:150px;max-width:150px;margin:5px">
    <div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
  </div>
```

I want image preview in horizontal center. How can I center align this div horizontally? I know because of float left row starting from the left side but I want that row start from center align.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning

Comment: Then How can I align it horizontally center?

Comment: Remove the position absolute from the image. Replace the Float:left on the div with this: "display:block;margin:auto;".

Comment: Easiest way (but old school method) is to place your image tags between <center> tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning multiple images horizontally in the center of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434022/aligning-multiple-images-horizontally-in-the-center-of-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align: center;position: relative;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin:5px;"> 
            <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin:5px"> 
            <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block;margin:5px;">
            <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin:5px;">
            <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px;" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

It should be better if you add classes to the elements and if you need to modify it, you just do it one time.

Comment: I will add a class once this issue resolves BTW thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

top: 50% means, that elements top side is placed in 50% of the parents one. Same goes with left attribute.

To center image horizontaly I would recomend using margin instead of absolute position.

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: But I want to center align sub div not image

Comment: This will position the image only in the div, but upper div is only 150px;

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <img style="max-width:150px;display:inline-block" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
  <img style="max-width:150px;display:inline-block" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
  <img style="max-width:150px;display:inline-block" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
  <img style="max-width:150px;display:inline-block" src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
</div>
```

Simply display the child elements as inline block and set the `text-align` property of of the parent to `center`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code. Please let me know if it helps

```
  <div style="width:100%; margin-left:20% ">
   <div style="width:150px;max-width:150px;float:left;margin: 5px;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px; " 
      src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
   <div style="width:150px;max-width:150px;float:left;margin: 5px;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px; " 
      src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
   <div style="width:150px;max-width:150px;float:left;margin: 5px;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px; " 
      src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
   <div style="width:150px;max-width:150px;float:left;margin: 5px;"> <img style="height:auto;width:auto;max-width: 150px;max-height: 150px; " 
      src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple way to do this.**

```
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but I think you're looking for something like this.

```
.flex-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

```
<div class="flex-center">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/472075/POLAN_preview.jpg">
</div>
```

See this [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x0axhkkw/10/)